# What is the difference between the prefixes по and у in verbs of motion

Tags: глаголы-движения

I have been studying Russian for a while and have looked at a number of grammar books for Russian by I fail to see the nuance between 'по' and 'у'
For example:

Мой самолёт улетит...
vs. 
Мой самолёт полетит...

Thanks

Comment: по—set-off, go// У-leave, depart

Answer (score 5):

The prefix *По-* with verbs of motion has two main meanings
1. Beginning of motion — perfective aspect. Что сделать?(unidirectional)
пойти,
поехать,
полететь,
побежать,
Куда? К кому? Where? To whom?
**в, на,к** (prepositions used after verbs)

> Я пошёл на работу.
>   Машина поехала после остановки.
>   Мальчик побежал.
>   Самолет полетел в Москву. Я полечу завтра.

2. A little bit, for a short while, insignificantly– perfective aspect. Что сделать?(multidirectional)
   походить,
   поездить,
   полетать,
   побегать
   Где? По чему? Where? Across what?
   по (the preposition used after verbs)

> Я походил по парку немного. Птицы полетали и сели на дерево.

The prefix *У-* means 
1 Somebody’s absence in the given place, departure from the place.
уходить/уйти
уезжать/уехать Imperfective/perfective, unidirectional.
Откуда? От кого?From where?From whom?
из, с, от(prepositions used after the verbs)

> Мы улетаем утром из Домодедово.
>   Он улетел, но обещал вернуться.
>   После каникул студенты снова уезжают из дома.

Answer (score 4):

As prefixes for motion verbs, ***у-*** usually emphasises on a place from which the motion starts, while ***по-*** makes emphasis on a trajectory of motion (implying that the destination is a subject to change, though such a distinction, that is, an uncertain route, is not mandatory). Cf:

***Я скоро уеду.*** (The ellipsis topic is about the place from which the speaker is about to start)/

***Я уезжаю сегодня*** (Again, the speaker emphasises that (s)he is about to part.

***Он уехал.*** (He is no more here).

***Я скоро поеду.*** (I am having a destination to part in the nearmost future).

***Я поеду сегодня*** (I am about to take a new route today; I am going to part today and I want to inform you that I have some destination, though it's not certain).

***Он поехал / поехавший.*** (He's crazy; he's out of common sense).

Hence, ***Мой самолёт улетит...***  = My plane is to leave this place..

***Мой самолёт полетит...*** = My plane is about to fly along a trajectory (though it's not a definate one)...

Bot phrases suggest something a little bit extraodinary / unusual about the flight. To describe a regular flight, one might say something like

***Мой самолёт улетает /вылетает  /вылетел***... = My plane leaves this place (as it is usually supposed to fly)